# Requesting image size with exact dimensions from Android app

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to request an image with exact dimensions from my android app.  The image server I'm hitting allows me to specify dimensions at the end of the URL and the server accepts crop input, but I also need to do this with a google static map.

Say I have an image view with a width of match_parent and a height of 300dp.  How can I pass these dimensions?

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Australia&size=**640x400**

I know that I can get the pixel size for a dp value, so I can store 300dp in my dimens and then get the pixels for it, and I can get the width using display metrics.

My Nexus 5 development phone returns **1080px wide x 900px tall** using this approach.  The problem is that 1080x900 is a huge image, and doing this repeatedly on my image server, say for a list view of images, is taxing on phone memory and data consumption.

So in this case, 1080x900 passed to an image server, or google static maps, would give me a perfectly fitting image.  How can I request something lesser of this and still have it appear half decent, not pixelated, and still scaled?  I've tried approaches like width/2 and height/2 but am not convinced that this is ideal.

Thanks for all input!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might try dividing the sizes by 2 or some other value, that would shrink the sizes by 4.

Comment: I've tried dividing by two and it definitely reduces image quality, but it's not a complete pixelated mess for the static map.  For the other usage, when requesting an image from my image server, it's pretty bad.  If this is the standard approach, I'll stick with it.  Figured I'd ask though in case there was some magical feature or approach that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: I just tested the link, it sends the images in png format. While I have never used the google api before, if there is a way to request jpg you might consider that. You can get a good deal more compression from that format.